# Phone7 Communicating over the teather

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to have a phone7 application communicate with a desktop application via the USB tether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. This functionality is not possible unless the desktop app is running a web service or can recieve communication over HTTP.
There is currently no other way to do this.

Comment: Ah so it can call out to a web service over USB via HTTP? that's an option. Do you know where I can find an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you decide to sniff the USB traffic and see the model by which the exchange occurs (e.g. phone -> Zune Client). This is what some applications do (e.g. the unofficial phone explorer).

Directly via the exposed API - not really.